# Yii2 ActiveForm field widgets not posting values to the model

Tags: php, forms, yii2, widget

I'm trying to incorporate a DateTimePicker widget into an ActiveForm in Yii2 as a field like this in the View:

```
 $form->field($model, 'date_from')->widget(DateTimePicker::className(),
    [
        'value' => '2013-01-01T00:00:00Z',
        'readonly' => true,
        'removeButton' => false,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ',
            'autoclose' => true,
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ],
    ]);
```

Upon submission, it validates as empty and does not pass a value to the model. The widget also does not display the default value in the text field, despite the value attribute being set.

I can make the process work by displaying the widget like this in the view:

```
 echo '<label class="control-label">From</label>';
    echo DateTimePicker::widget([
       'name' => 'ModelName[date_from]',
       'value' => '2013-01-01T00:00:00Z',
       'readonly' => true,
       'removeButton' => false,
       'pluginOptions' => [
           'format' => 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ',
           'autoclose' => true,
           'class' => 'form-control',
       ],
   ]);
```

with this in the Controller:

```
 public function actionName()
    {
          $model = new ModelName();
          if ($model->load(($data = Yii::$app->request->post())) && $model->execquery()) {
          Yii::$app->session->setFlash('formSubmitted');
          $model->from = time('yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ', strtotime($data['ModelName']['date_from']));
          $model->to = time('yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ', strtotime($data['ModelName']['date_to']));
          return $this->render('name', ['model' => $model]);
        }
        return $this->render('name', ['model' => $model]);
     }
```

The cooresponding values in the model look like this:

```
public $text1;
public $text2;
public $date_from;
public $date_to;
public $email;

/**
 * @return array the validation rules.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // positions and dates are required
        [['text1', 'text2', 'date_to', 'date_from'], 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
    ];
}
```

The text input fields in my form work fine. Is there something more I need to add to the controller or the model to ensure the widget values are posted on submit?

I am using the Kartik DateTimePicker widget https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker, but I have tried using other widgets with the same problem, so presumably I'm missing something in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the documentation of DateTimePicker widget,I have seen the usage with model and Active Form (with no default initial value) like

```
// Usage with model and Active Form (with no default initial value)
echo $form->field($model, 'date_from')->widget(DateTimePicker::classname(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter event time ...'],
    'readonly' => true,
    'removeButton' => false,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ',            
        'autoclose' => true,            
    ]
]);
```

Source http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datetimepicker

**I have not seen the usage of 'value' => 'xxxxxxx' there.(If value is used then there is a name attribute also in other examples)**.But the documentation says the widget can have all parameters that one would pass for any Yii Input Widget. But my suggestion is to remove it and give a try.If you want to set a default value,then pass it from the controller.

The controller code should be like

```
 public function actionName()
    {
         $model = new ModelName();
         if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) 
         {
             Yii::$app->session->setFlash('formSubmitted');                 
             return $this->render('name', ['model' => $model]);
         }
         else
         {
            $model->date_from= "2013-01-01T00:00:00Z";//some default value
            return $this->render('name', ['model' => $model]);
         }
    }
```

Otherwise you always have the option to use

```
echo '<label class="control-label">From</label>';
    echo DateTimePicker::widget([
       'name' => 'ModelName[date_from]',
       'value' => '2013-01-01T00:00:00Z',
       'readonly' => true,
       'removeButton' => false,
       'pluginOptions' => [
           'format' => 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ',
           'autoclose' => true,
           'class' => 'form-control',
       ],
   ]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there something more I need to add to the controller to force the first way to pass the date_from value to the model? This seems to happen automatically for text input fields, but my $model->date_from stays null.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by putting the $model->execquery() call after the values were set:

```
public function actionName()
    {
          $model = new ModelName();
          if ($model->load(($data = Yii::$app->request->post()))) {
              Yii::$app->session->setFlash('formSubmitted');
              $model->from = time('yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ', strtotime($data['ModelName']['date_from']));
              $model->to = time('yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ', strtotime($data['ModelName']['date_to']));
              $model->execquery();
              return $this->render('name', ['model' => $model]);
          }
          return $this->render('name', ['model' => $model]);
     }
```